# Путаница с ветками в git

Tags: git, git-branch

Делали релиз проекта, замержили ветку `dev` в `master`. Потом что-то пошло не по плану и было сделано 2 хотфикса из ветки `dev-release` прямо в `master`. Эти хотфиксы не решили проблему и был сделан откат 3 коммитов в ветке `master`.

Сейчас в master старая версия проекта и когда пытаемся замержить `dev` с новой версией в `master`, то в `master'е` остается старая версия + накладываются некоторые изменения от новой. Конфликтов нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно смежить ветку `dev` в `master`, чтоб в приоритете были изменения из ветки `dev`. В случае конфиктов применялись изменения из ветки `dev`. Доступа к мастеру у меня нет, нужно делать через дополнительные ветки.

Comment: я бы сделал `get reset --hard HASH` и потом `git  push --force`. Чтобы откатить состояние ветки до того как в неё вливали. а потом уже мержился

Comment: @pavel я дополнил свой вопрос. У меня нету доступа к мастеру